# Как организовать поиск и чтение данных из файла?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, файлы

У меня есть форма C# WinForms, в которой я могу управлять моей БД (добавлять записи, удалять и т.д.) Также у меня есть файл, в котором хранятся 7000 записей. 
Если я в форме редактирую запись, то сразу после редактирования сразу же должна изменяться соответствующая запись в файле. То есть мне нужно как-то получить местоположение записи в файле. Файл бинарный.

Выгружать все содержимое в программу каждый раз не подойдет. Нужно напрямую работать с файлом. Как мне организовать это дело?

Comment: Менять одну запись в середине файла можно только в том случае, если все записи **строго** одной длины. В противном случае читайте весь файл целиком в память. Потом перезаписывайте тоже целиком.

Comment: Строки одинаковой длины, мне кажется, очень удобно. Спасибо.